# Facing issues in HTTP Callout over https using external systems Certificate

Tags: apexrest

I am trying to integrate external system with Salesforce to invoke external system's API over https. I have got two certificates from external system, one is keystore.jks and other one is truststore.jks. I could successfully import keystore.jks but while importing truststore.jks; I am getting error message in Salesforce that 'keystore file doesnt contain a PrivateKey entry'.

With keystore.jks imported, I tried HTTP Callout with external system end-point and it worked. However when I replaced the end-point with https, I am getting error message that CertificateException:No subject alternative names matching IP address A.B.C.D found.

Can someone please help me figure out if this issue is because I could not import trustsore.jks file or there is any other way to solve the issue?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For importing CA-Signed certificates please follow the below steps in this help article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&type=5. You can check this article also https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hqIGAAY

Comment: Hi, this issue is now resolved. The CA from external system was not the trusted signing authority from the list of Salesforce trusted authority. External System signed their certificate from one of the trusted authority who appears to be in the list of Salesforce trusted list and the issue is resolved. Thanks for your help!